# aligning rails form_for button integrated with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

im not the greatest at CSS. Just following the tutorial and added a little flavor to my site. My Sign up page for the site:

[image]

How do I align the button to the middle? And is it possbile to shorten the length of the boxes?

Here is the code for my signup page

```
     <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
        <h1>Sign up</h1>

          <div class="row">
           <div class="span6 offset3">
             <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'})  do |f| %>
                <fieldset>

                <div class = "form-group">
                  <%= f.label :name, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                  <div class = "col-sm-10">
                  <%= f.text_field :name , :class => "form-control" %>
                 </div>
                </div>
               <div class = "form-group">
                 <%= f.label :email, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                 <div class = "col-sm-10">
                   <%= f.text_field :email , :class => "form-control" %>
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class = "form-group">
                 <%= f.label :password, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                 <div class = "col-sm-10">
                   <%= f.password_field :password , :class => "form-control" %>
                </div>
               </div>


              <div class = "form-group">
               <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
                 <div class = "col-sm-10">
                   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation , :class => "form-control" %>
             </div>
         </div>

            <div class = "form-actions">
             <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <% end %>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is there CSS to go with this? Have you tried to text-align the submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using Bootstrap3 whereas the tutorial is Bootstrap2.

In Bootstrap3, `span6 offset3` doesn't work.
Instead, it must be something like this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
    <h1>Sign up</h1>

      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```

Also, you'll get the nice Bootstrap3 large button by replacing `btn-large` with `btn-lg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS

```
div.center, p.center, img.center {
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In your HTML

```
<div class = "center form-actions">
             <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V7E7f/)

Answer (score 0):

It's all easily done with CSS:

alignment of submit button:

```
div.form-actions { width: 100%; text-align: center;}
```

size of input fields:

```
.form-control { width: 150px; }
```

Comment: if i change the width, the form gets smaller which  is fine. but then it looks funny because the alignment is all off. How do i move the form- control more right so it looks more nice?